# JPA method to lazy-load a whole entity graph without 1+n+n*m queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Let's imagine I have these entity classes (I omitted the JPA annotations):

```
class TableA { Long id; List<TableB> tableBs; }
class TableB { Long id; List<TableC> tableCs; }
class TableC { Long id; List<TableD> tableDs; }
class TableD { Long id; int foo; }
```

This gives us this entity "graph"/"dependencies":

```
TableA ---OneToMany--> TableB ---OneToMany--> TableC ---OneToMany--> TableD
```

If I want to deeply load all sub-entities, sub-sub-entities and sub-sub-sub-entities of one TableA object, JPA will produce these queries:

- 1 query to get one TableA: it's fine, of course
- 1 query to lazy-load tableA.getTableBs(): it's fine too => we get n TableB entities
- n queries to lazy-load all tableA.getTableBs()[1..n].getTableCs() => we get m TableC entities per TableB entity
- n*m queries to lazy-load all tableA.getTableBs()[1..n].getTableCs()[1..m].getTableDs()

I'd like to avoid this 1+n*(m+1) queries to lazy-load all sub-sub-sub-entities of my TableA object.

If I had to do the queries by hand, I'd just need *4* queries:

- SAME: 1 query to get one TableA
- SAME: 1 query to lazy-load tableA.getTableBs(): it's fine
- BETTER: 1 query to get all TableC WHERE id IN (tableA.getTableBs()[1..n].getId()) // The "IN" clause is computed in Java, I do one SQL query, and then from the TableC{id,parentTableBId,...} result, I populate each TableB.getTableC() list with Java
- WAY BETTER: 1 query to get all TableD WHERE id IN (tableA.getTableBs()[1..n].getTableCs()[1..m].getId()) // Same IN-clause-computing and tree-traversal to assign all TableD childs to each TableC parents

I'd like to call either:

- JpaMagicUtils.deeplyLoad(tableA); // and it does the "IN" clauses building (possibly splitting into 2 or 3 queries to have have too many "IN" ids) + tree children assignation itself, or
- JpaMagicUtils.deeplyLoad(tableA, "getTablesBs().getTableCs()"); JpaMagicUtils.deeplyLoad(tableA, "getTableBs().getTableCs().getTableDs()"); // to populate one level at a time, and have a better granularity of which fields to load in bulk, and which fields not to load.

I don't think there is a way with JPA for that.

- Or is there a way with JPA for that?
- Or as a non-JPA-standard way, but perhaps with Hibernate? or with another JPA implementation?
- Or is there a library that we can use just to do that (on top of any JPA implementation, or one implementation in particular)?

Answer (score 1):

> If I had to do the queries by hand, I'd just need 4 queries

Well, why not one query joining four tables?

Seriously though, if you want to limit the number of queries, I'd first try Hibernate's `@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)` (not sure if there are similar annotations for other JPA providers). It is a hint that tells Hibernate to use a join to load child entities (rather than issuing a separate query). It does not always work for nested one-to-many associations, but I'd try defining it at the deepest level of the hierarchy and then working your way up until you find the performance acceptable (or the size of the result set forbidding).

If you're looking for generic solution, then sadly I do not know any JPA provider that would follow the algorithm you describe, neither in general nor as an opt-in feature. This is a very specific use case, and I guess the price of being robust as a library is not incorporating optimizations for special-case scenarios.

Note: if you want to eagerly load an entity hierarchy in one use case but keep the entities lazily-loaded in general scenarios, you'll want to look up JPA entity graphs. You may also need to write a custom query using `FETCH JOIN`, but I don't think nested `FETCH JOINS` are generally supported.